# How to distinguish if button was pressed on the main window or on the email opened in a separate window?

Tags: .net, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Problem is when user detaches email and use the add-in.  He thinks, and I understand why, that he is operating on the email he can see in front of him.  But the implementation is:

`Selection selection = app.ActiveExplorer().Selection ;`

So, user actually is acting on the selection from the explorer, which is on the main window.  My question is:

How to check where the button was pressed?  Was it the main window with the explorer, or detached email in a separate window?

P.S.  Button is placed on the ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You button click handler takes RibbonControl as a parameter. Cast RibbonControl.Context as either Explorer or Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is to check the [ActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865654.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which returns returns an object representing the current Microsoft Outlook window on the desktop, either an *Explorer* or an *Inspector* object. Returns Nothing if no Outlook explorer or inspector is open.

The second way (straight) is to check out the [Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff861184.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the IRibbonControl interface which represents the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure. You can read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)